# Word for someone obsessed with an unreal or alternate universe (eg. trekkie, but in general)?

Tags: general-vs-specific

Is there a general term for someone obsessed with an unreal or alternate universe/reality?  Like a Trekkie or someone obsessed with Star Wars, such that they research and spend time philosophizing about that alternate universe/"reality" and maybe even ordering their life around some of those philosophies?

Comment: _Delusional._ springs to mind.

Comment: I guess I should have added that they still maintain that it is not a real alternate universe, so it wouldn't really be a delusion.

Comment: Star Wars and Star Trek aren't real? Now who's being delusional? ¦Þ    How about: _Enthusiast_?

Comment: Haha. Yeah enthusiast seems closer, something in the middle between delusional and enthusiast, if that exists is I think what I'm looking for.

Comment: _Delusiast._  lol

Comment: *fanboy* / *fangirl*

Comment: [*Parallel universe enthusiast*](https://books.google.ca/books?id=7GlKED0Mlg0C&pg=PA257&dq=alternate+universe+enthusiast&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CBsQ6AEwAGoVChMItq_XlZiuyAIVxSweCh3gYwuW#v=onepage&q=%22parallel%20universe%20enthusiast%22&f=false).

Comment: "Fiction universe addict" ?

Comment: head in the clouds

Comment: Stack Exchange member

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Escapist** -a person who is obsessed with the habitual diversion of the mind to purely imaginative activity or entertainment as an escape from reality or routine.

[Link-MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/escapism) (Definition is modified to describe a *person*.)

Comment: I think this is closest to what I was thinking of, someone knows it's not real but they choose to escape to it as though it were reality.

Answer (score 1):

In America, the word "fanatic" captures well the elevation of a secular obsession.

"Religious", in the colloquial sense works; though if they are obsessed and order their life around it, then an argument could be made for the literal.

"Delusional" seems pejorative.

Answer (score 0):

Consider **sci fi geek**.

sci fi geek: a person who always goes to a Star Trek or StarWars convention or someone who is always first in line for a new SF movie such as StarWars. ([Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=sci+fi+geek))

geek: a person who has excessive enthusiasm for and some expertise about a specialized subject or activity: *a foreign-film geek* ([Random House](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/geek))